# Orthogonal polynomials with respect to the lognormal distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, orthogonal-polynomials

I am currently doing some inspection on the orthogonal polynomials with respect to the lognormal distribution. Does anyone already work on that or know some cool references?

All the best,

Pierre-O.

Comment: Please note that the orthogonal polynomials for the lognormal distribution are not dense in $L_2$ equipped with the measure induced by the lognormal (see the article by Ernst et. al. http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/m2an/2011045).

Comment: Yes, I know see proposition 1.1 in http://pierre-olivier.goffard.me/Publications/Asmussen_Goffard_Laub_LogNormalPolynomialApproximation.pdf

Comment: Maybe less technical than what is proposed in the article you make reference to. I will definitely have a look at it even though I am not sure to understand. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Interesting article. I've never seen the approach in approximating density ratios. We only do expansions of random variables in orthogonal polynomials and I frequently have to warn people (students/engineers) not to use lognormals as basis random variables in their expansions. So maybe it's good that the comment is there to warn other people.

Comment: Expansion of random variables? Is it related to Malliavin calculus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orthogonal polynomials with respect to the lognormal distribution go by the name of [Stieltjes-Wigert polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes%E2%80%93Wigert_polynomials). Two recent studies of their properties:

- [Global Asymptotics of
  Stieltjes-Wigert Polynomials](http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5193)
- [Variations of
  Stieltjes-Wigert and q-Laguerre polynomials and their recurrence
  coefficients](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.3960)

Comment: Thank you, let see if this factor 1/x in the lognormal pdf is not an issue. Cheers.